# mongoose sort doesn't work using find()

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
Sales.find({
         "email":req.body.email, 
         "createAt": {
         "$gte": firstDayOfMonth(month),
         "$lte": lastDayOfMonth(month)
         },
         "sort":{
            createAt: -1 //Sort by Date Added DESC
         }
        }, function(err,response){
            callback(err,response);
        });
```

Any clue why this mongoose query doesn't work? I'm sure it's sort problem coz when I remove the sort part I'm able to get some data.

Comment: protip: sanitize that email field. There is no guarantee that a field straight out of `req.body` isn't going to be malformed or even maliciously trying to exploit whatever bug someone knows about mongoose that you don't. That said: you've given us no information to help you figure out your problem. Where's the rest that shows us the sample data that proves this should even find anything? (e.g. what's in your database, what's in req.body.email, what does your callback see for err and response, etc)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans u don't to have to know so much to know what's wrong with the code above coz I'd alrdy said, if I remove the sort it will work.

Comment: you are quite mistaken in that assumption. There is nothing weird about this find query, so show enough code to constitute a [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this code,

```
var queryOptions = {
    $and: [{
        'createAt': {
            "$gte": firstDayOfMonth(month),
            "$lte": lastDayOfMonth(month)

        }
    }, {
        'email': req.body.email
    }]
}
Sales
    .find(queryOptions)
    .sort('-createAt')
    .exec(function(err, response) {
        return res.status(200).json(response);

    }).catch(function(error) {
        return res.status(500).json(error);
    });
```

Comment: I can't use exec() because I'm using a middleware call async.

Comment: @MariaJane Glad to help you

Answer (score 1):

Try with this, It will work with ES6

```
Sales.find({
     "email":req.body.email, 
     "createAt": {
     "$gte": firstDayOfMonth(month),
     "$lte": lastDayOfMonth(month)
     },
     "sort":{
        [createAt]: -1 //Sort by Date Added DESC
     }
    }, function(err,response){
        callback(err,response);
    });
```